# Bitcoin Daemon Syncing Crashing Server. CPU through the roof

Tags: bitcoind

we run a Bitcoin Daemon on a Linode server.

We're seeing huge CPU usage to the point its crashing our server.

We're not mining, simply running a node.

Can you help?

Comment: Can you please add details such as client version and whether you are using a bootstrap file or downloading and verifying the blockchain from scratch?  Or is the blockchain already up to date?

Answer (score 1):

The bitcoin daemon takes around 24 hours on a good server to sync to the network. During this time CPU usage is very high as it is verifying the blockchain from scratch.

Once synced, bitcoind is a far lighter program.